# Assembly Language Compiler

Tags: linux, ubuntu, assembly

I need a compiler of Assembly Language for LINUX.
Can you help me with a link?
Currently I am using EMU8086 for windows.
But I need this compiler for LINUX OS.

Comment: I strongly recommend installing a Linux distribution, perhaps in a virtual machine.

Comment: Off-topic, since asking for resources. The `binutils`package provides the GNU `as` assembler and is installed by default (if you have installed `gcc` or `clang`).  The `nasm` package is separate and provides a different assembler syntax.

Comment: You can run EMU8086 under Wine, but if you want to mess around with 16-bit DOS / PC-BIOS stuff, use NASM + BOCHS under Linux.  Or use NASM and/or gcc to make native 32-bit or 64-bit executables.

Comment: @PeterCordes nasm + dosbox isn't closer to emu8086 situation? Hmm... I should probably try bochs sometimes to get better idea, actually it has some built-in tools for debugging (while dosbox does not by default, has to be recompiled from source with different configuration to have some debug support)? Then the nasm+bochs is probably closer to emu8086.

Comment: @Ped7g: I forget if BOCHS comes with a full DOS environment for code that uses `int 21h`.  But BOCHS enables the built-in debugger by default, and that's a *key* part of an asm dev setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Assembly you don't have a compiler, you need an assembler and a linker.
I am using [nasm](http://nasm.us/) to assemble my code and gcc to link in Linux.

Comment: `gcc` will invoke `ld` (and sometimes `as`) from the `binutils` package (which is almost always installed)